# Search bar above listview with all contacts not working.?

Tags: android, search, android-listview, contacts

I had fetched the contacts from my application and showed it on a list view. I want to add a search bar on the  listview. I had tried the following code. But it is not working fine.  This is the code I am working on:

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
          // When user changed the Text
     Toast.makeText(context, cs.toString()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList).getFilter().filter(cs.toString());   
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
              int arg3) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
  });
```

This is the getFiletr method:

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Filter filter=new Filter(){

        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "inside publish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Log.d("inside publish", "inside publish");
            mDisplayedValues = (ArrayList<ListData>) results.values; 
            notifyDataSetChanged();  
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); 
             ArrayList<ListData> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
             Toast.makeText(context, "inside perform", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.d("insde perform", "inside perform");
             if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "original data is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.d("original data is null", "original data is null");   
                 mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<ListData>(mDisplayedValues); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

             if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "constraint is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // set the Original result to return  
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                }

             else {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "constraint not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).title;
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            ListData ld=new ListData();
                            ld.setTitle(mOriginalValues.get(i).title);;
                            ld.setDescription(mOriginalValues.get(i).Description);
                            ld.setImg(mOriginalValues.get(i).image);
                            FilteredArrList.add(ld);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "added"+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "results stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             Toast.makeText(context, "before returning results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("before returning results","before returning results");
             return results;
        }
    };
    Toast.makeText(context, "before returning filter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("before returning filter","before returning filter");
    return filter;
}
```

Please help

Comment: What is the problem? Anyway why you create a new object reuse the object of the original items no? Anyway make sure you added the right ArrayList in getCount and getView. Could get excetion and problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one i used this code in my application and it's working fine.

defiantly it will help you.

```
 SContactListBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
          // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int count, int after)
        {
        // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }


        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int before, int count)
        {
        textlength = SContactListBox.getText().length();
        array_sort.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Contact_NameList.size(); i++)
        {
        if (textlength <= Contact_NameList.get(i).length())
        {

            if((boolean)
                    Contact_NameList.get(i).contains(SContactListBox.getText().toString()))
           {
           array_sort.add(Contact_NameList.get(i));
           check=false;
              }
             }
            }
        ClistAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(ContactListActivity.this, array_sort);
        listContacts.setAdapter(ClistAdapter);


        }
        });
```